# Is it Possible to Cast a List to an IList of a Different Type?

Tags: c#

The following Source is bound to an Items Source property of a Grid and no idea why this cast is not possible; I get the following error: "Unable to cast object of type List to IList." What is wrong and what would be the work around in this case?

```
public IList<TypeTwo> Source { get; set; }

  public SomeViewModel()
    {
      List<TypeOne> result = db.GetInfo().ToList();
      Source = (IList<TypeTwo>)result;

     // This works if the IList is of Type TypeOne
     // Source = db.GetInfo().ToList();
    }

  public class TypeTwo {
       // The same properties of TypeOne
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the each element separately, not the whole list at once :

```
Source = result
    .Select(x => new TypeTwo()
    {
         SharedProperty1 = x.SharedProperty1,
         SharedProperty2 = x.SharedProperty2,
         ....
    })
    .ToList();

// only if TypeTwo derives from TypeOne, or implements an explicit cast operator
//Source = result.Cast<TypeTwo>().ToList();
```